# Atualizar recyclerview de outro fragmento, no mesmo viewpager

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, viewpager

Tenho um viewpager que contem 3 fragmentos, sendo um para transações realizadas,um para transações canceladas e outro para transações em aberto.Cada fragmento possui um recyclerview para a exibição das transações e também, cada fragmento possui um swiperefreshlayout para que o usuário possa obter do servidor as informações mais recentes. Minha duvida é o seguinte: Como faço para atualizar a lista do fragmento 1 e também a lista do fragmento 2 e 3 se necessário ?

Ex: ao efetuar a atualização do fragmento de transações em aberto, e verificar que o arrayList tem elementos a menos, logicamente a transação que estava em aberto, foi para o fragmento de transações em canceladas ou realizadas. Assumindo que houve essa modificação no arrayList, eu gostaria de atualizar também fragmento 2 e 3 se necessário.

PS: ambos estão no mesmo viewpager, já tentei via interface e não consegui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim, vamos supor que esta no fragmento de transação em aberto e vai atualizar o fragmento de transação realizada. No fragmento de transação realizada você faz um método atualizarAdapter

```
    private void updateFragment() {

    SeuFragmentTransacaoRealizada fragment =
            (SeuFragmentTransacaoRealizada) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + posicaoTab);

    if (fragment != null) {

        if (fragment.getView() != null) {

            fragment.atualizarAdapter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ola, segui sua linha de pensamento e deu certo, porem tive que fazer algumas alterações, o método getChildFragmentManager() foi alterado para getFragmentManager() e para que o atualizarAdapter() funcionasse, tive que implementar uma interface na qual esperava um resultado de updateFragment(). Vlw

Comment: Imaginei que fosse fazer no fragmento por isso mudei para getChildFragmentManager(). Mas que bom que deu certo.